# Получение onclick с помощью jQuery

Tags: jquery

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться, не могу получить значение `onclick`.

Есть ссылка вида

```
<span class="flist-values" id="flist-values-other2">
<a href="javascript://" onclick="return categoryFilter('other2',2)">да</a>
</span>
```

Как мне из нее выдернуть `onclick`?

---

ОТВЕТ:

(спасибо всем кто помогал!)

```
$('document').ready(function () {
var i = 0;

// это цикл по всем элементам .flist-item
$('.flist-item').each(function(){
i++;

// получаю значение onclick в переменную text
var text = $(this).find('a').attr('onclick');

// искомая строка - название функции, скобка, кавычка :)
var search = 'categoryFilter(\'';

// нахожу позицию, с которой начинаются аргументы
var argsStart = text.indexOf(search)+search.length;

// получаю аргументы
text = text.substring(argsStart, text.indexOf(')', argsStart));

// получаю массив из двух элементов
var result = text.split('\',')

// это увидите в консоли браузера
cf1 = result[0];
cf2 = result[1];

var htmlrepl = '<input type="checkbox" id='+i+' name='+cf1+' value='+cf2+'>';
$("#flist-values-other"+i).html(htmlrepl);

    });

});
```

Comment: что именно ты хочешь получить/выдернуть из onclick?

return нужен чтобы предотвратить дальнейшую обработку, т.е. чтобы он не перешел по href.

Comment: categoryFilter('other2',2)

обе переменные в функции могут меняться...

Comment: @Dimastik86 вместо i++ можете использовать индекс цикла, .each(function(index){

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А можно еще вот так попробовать:

```
$('document').ready(function () {

    // это цикл по всем элементам .flist-item
    $('.flist-item').each(function(){

        // получаю значение onclick в переменную text
        var text = $(this).find('a').attr('onclick');
        // искомая строка - название функции, скобка, кавычка :)
        var search = 'categoryFilter(\'';
        // нахожу позицию, с которой начинаются аргументы
        var argsStart = text.indexOf(search)+search.length;

        // получаю аргументы
        text = text.substring(argsStart, text.indexOf(')', argsStart));
        // получаю массив из двух элементов
        var result = text.split('\',')

        // это увидите в консоли браузера
        console.log(result[0]); // первый аргумент
        console.log(result[1]); // второй аргумент
        console.log('-----');  // просто разделитель
    });

});
```

Этот код проходит все элементы `.flist-item` (см. each()), ищет там ссылку, получает содерижмое `onclick`;
После этого находит в нём `categoryFilter('` и забрает всё, что после него, но до следующей закрывающей скобки. Потом разделяет строку на две.

Но проблема в формировании. Лучшим решением было бы передавать эти параметры каким-то более доступным образом.

Comment: это для меня пока сложновато ((
я не понимаю что куда назначать в вашем коде ((

подскажите как мне просто выдернуть из ссылки categoryFilter(' и забрает всё, что после него, но до следующей закрывающей скобки.

и назначить значения на две переменные cf1 и cf2

Comment: @Dimastik86, смотрите комменты в обновленном ответе

Вместо ``console.log..`` напишете, что хотите: аргументы хранятся в result

Можно:

    cf1 = result[0];
    cf2 = result[1];

Comment: а как при использовании each() вести подсчет кругов циклов?!

Comment: Объявить переменную (``var i = 0;``) вне ``each()``, а внутри увеличивать значение (``i++``)

Answer (score 1):

Может вы это хотели?

```
<span class="flist-values" id="flist-values-other2">
<a href="javascript://" onclick="location.href = categoryFilter('other2',2); return false;">да</a>
</span>
```

Comment: нет, см выше...

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#flist-values-other2').on('click', function() {
   var onclick = $(this).attr('onclick');
   alert(onclick);
})
```

Comment: не срабатывает, пишет null 
http://jsfiddle.net/Dimastik86/ZSzPW/1/

    $('document').ready(function () {
        
    var countCH = $(".flist-label").length;
        
    for (i=1; i<= countCH; i++){
    
    $('#flist-values-other'+i).on('click', function() {
       var onclick = $(this).attr('onclick');
    })
    
        
    var htmlrepl = '<input type="checkbox" onclick='+onclick+'>';  
        
    $("#flist-values-other"+i).html(htmlrepl);
    }
        
    });

Comment: @Dimastik86 у вас не правильно составлена логика и соответственно код. Получение значения onclick происходит только при клике. Соответственно раньше ничего не произойдет. Еще пару небольших поправок внес, смотрите: http://pastebin.com/kHhV37Cw

Comment: ваш код у меня вообще работает не так как планировалось, к тому же онклик всеравно нулл

посмотрите, что не так, почему значение не могу добыть?
http://jsfiddle.net/Dimastik86/ZSzPW/2/

Comment: @Dimastik86  так?  http://jsfiddle.net/ZSzPW/4/

Answer (score 1):

Смотрим [пример тут](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/ZSzPW/6/). (*правильно выбирайте селекторы!*)

Answer (score 0):

а какже

```
alert($("#flist-values-other2").attr("onclick"));
```

Comment: alert($("#flist-values-other1").attr("onclick")); 

результат null